# Export the same range changed by a function to a PDF file

Tags: excel, vba

I have only found functions to export several sheets in a single PDF.

I want to export the same sheet and the same range, which is changing through a function, in a single PDF file.

For example, in the following code there is a loop that changes the values of a range three times.
How can I save a single PDF file that contains the range in triplicate and changed?

I tried arrays but I don't know how to implement in this specific case.

```vb
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 3
    Call function_to_change_values 'this function change the values of range A1 to D5
    'config printing:
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$D$5" 'print area
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = 77
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    End With
    'create PDF:
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="C:\myfile.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
Next i
```

Comment: You can't. Every sheet in an Excel file will be, at least, 1 page in the PDF file. And every export will create a single PDF file. You got 3 options: 1) Separate those 3 ranges in 3 different sheets and export them in a single file 2) Use the same sheet but export them into 3 different PDF files. 3) Use object `AcroExch.PDDoc` to merge the files into a single one after exporting them into 3 different files. You can read in page 69 [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf) but I think you need to buy Adobe, not just having Adobe Reader.

Comment: Copy/pastevalues the range to an empty sheet, with each copy destination moving down so the pasted information can be exported to a single file when done.